# An unexpected error occurred processing the request when requesting the layer definition Url

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, arcgis-rest-api

When I publish my MXD in ArcGIS 10.0, the service url which returns the layer definitions in json format returns an error.

```
{"currentVersion":10.05,"error":{"code":500, 
"message":"An unexpected error occurred processing the request.","details":[]}}],"tables":[]}
```

The url looks something like this:

```
http://myserver/arcgis/rest/services/myservice/MapServer/layers?f=json
```

The MXD contains 150-200 layers. If I remove a few of the layers near the bottom, it renders correctly. These layers at the bottom work fine in other MXDs.  If I remove the bottom layers to get it working, but try adding completely different layers, it fails.

I found the errors being logged in a file called restlog.txt. So it looks like a bug in the code that renders the layer definitions.

```
ERROR:Index was outside the bounds of the array.
   at ESRI.ArcGIS.REST.MapServer.MapLayerRequestHandler.get_LayerDefinitionExpression()
   at ESRI.ArcGIS.REST.MapServer.MapLayerJsonFormatter.WriteJsonResponse()
   at ESRI.ArcGIS.REST.JsonFormatter.WriteResponse()
```

Here is a public Url (not related to me) illustrating the error:
http://epamap5.epa.gov/ArcGIS/rest/services/EMEF/TRINAT_2012/MapServer/layers?f=json

Is there a documented or known bug in the 10.0 Arcgis server code that renders the layer definitions.

**Any idea how to get around this error and stay on 10.0?**

Comment: Have you enabled logging on your Server and looked at any errors that may pop up?

Comment: I didn't see anything errors in event viewer. Is there a ArcGis specific log?

Comment: Look through this help for some additional logs and information (http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//015400000448000000)

Comment: No errors in the logs. It does contain INFO2 and INFO3 entries. I will update the question.

Comment: I found the errors logged in a file called restlog.txt

Answer (score 1):

There is a documented bug for this issue: [NIM-063468](http://support.esri.com/en/bugs/nimbus/TklNMDYzNDY4).  According to the bug report,

> **Synopsis**: If one or more layers in a map that is published has a broken link,
>   .NET REST returns an "Index was outside the bounds of the array."
>   exception
>
> **Solution**: Update the map document to fix the broken layer(s).

*I was using ArcMap 10.2.2 to open and save the MXD file as a 10.0 document.  The MDX had no issues when opened in 10.2.2. However, when I opened the MXD in ArcMap 10.0 on the server, it displayed two layers with issues. (a red explanation point). From there I used 10.0 to fix the layers.*